# sending multiple objects to back-end post method using angular 4 http services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, http

Hi I am trying to send two objects using http post method to backend

my environment is angular4, typescirpt, asp.net MVC 5

but it is throwing 500 internal server error

the same approach if I am passing single object to the backend my backend method is getting called

here is the code with passing single object

```
clientSidePostCall(Results:any,Details:any):Observable<any>{
   return this._http.post(Global.ENDPOINT +'BackendMethod/',Results)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .catch((err:any) => { throw err; });
        }
```

the above code is working fine if I send **Results object**  to **BackendMethod if it is expecting single parameter**

The same code is not working if I send multiple objects to backendMethod when it is expecting two objcets.

```
   clientSidePostCall(Results:any,Details:any):Observable<any>{
       return this._http.post(Global.ENDPOINT +'BackendMethod/',Results,Details)
                .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
                .catch((err:any) => { throw err; });
            }
```

The above code is not working and throwing 500 internal server error

**here is my backend method signature**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage BackendMethod([FromBody] resultsType Results, [FromBody] detailsType Details)
```

please help me with this

and I am having another doubt that can we pass object in http.get in angular 4 and typescript

Answer (score 4):

In your angular code make the Results, and Details be properties of a larger object... So send this object:

```
const myPostBody = { resultsType: Results, detailsType: Details }

return this._http.post(Global.ENDPOINT +'BackendMethod', myPostBody)
                .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
                .catch((err:any) => { throw err; });
            }
```

Also make sure that your API class type Results actually matches the Class Results that you're sending it

Comment: I have followed that, Thank you Kevin

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how asp.net works but the third argument of HttpClient.post is not for another post body. In fact a post request cannot have two bodies.  If your backend expects an array, do:

```
this._http.post(url, [Results, Details])
```

Comment: Will server will deserialize it in correct form? I doubt

Comment: Depends on the server. If it's JSON-decoding the body and expects it to be an array, yes.

Comment: Ie. whatever you pass to post() as the body, gets JSON encoded and sent as the raw post body by default.

Comment: In JSON it cannot.. An array is [1, 2, { "foo": 12} ] and object is {"a":1, "foo":"foo"}

Comment: As said, I don't know asp.net enough to tell from the code snippet what the server is expecting, an array or a few nested objects?

Comment: I didn't know, this deserialization happens out of the box.. Nice to know that, please share the reference I can further readup on it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166345/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-funkizer).

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping up child entities in a parent entity is required for HTTP Post. The child entity would usually be a business entity. 
On the receiving service end, you will use the entity names as properties to receive the individual items. All this assume your entity itself is serializable.